# How to document the method's attributes along with the method?

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, comments

Is it possible to include an attribute information in the generated xml documentation together with the method's documentation?

For example, this code:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     This is a summary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [MyAttribute("one", "two", "three")]
    public string MyMethod(string s)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

will produce something like this in the XML documentation:

```
    <member name="M:MyNameSpace.MyMethod(System.String)">
        <summary>
            This is a summary.
        </summary>
        <param name="s"></param>
        <returns></returns>
    </member>
```

Is there any way I could get something like this in the XML documentation:

```
    <member name="M:MyNameSpace.MyMethod(System.String)">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="MyAttribute">
                <param name="one"/>
                <param name="two"/>
                <param name="three"/>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
        <summary>
            This is a summary.
        </summary>
        <param name="s"></param>
        <returns></returns>
    </member>
```

Thanks in advance for all the answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Attributes for Documentation in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670879/using-attributes-for-documentation-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm not trying to use attributes to decorate the documentation, but it's the other way around. I'm trying to document attributes too, along with the methods, properties, classes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure. But reading the following

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

you should be able to get

```
<member name="M:MyNameSpace.MyMethod(System.String)">
    <attribute name="MyAttribute" values = "1,2,3">
    </attribute>
    <summary>
        This is a summary.
    </summary>
    <param name="s"></param>
    <returns></returns>
</member>
```

by using

```
///<attribute name="MyAttribute" values="1,2,3"></attribute>
```

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx you can read:

> The compiler will process any tag that is valid XML.

so I guess what you want can be done

Comment: "attribute" is not a valid tag for documentation tools such as Sandcastle.

Comment: Im' sure you are right, but I just answering to the question: "how to produce XML". The XML may not be designed to run with SandCastle

Comment: You might want to mention that in your answer.